# apache2 moddav set files to be executable?

Tags: apache-2.2

With apache2 mod_dav, where on earth do I set "executable T" so that uploaded files have the execute permission?

I need to do this so that users can upload CGI scripts.

Comment: What is "executable T"?

Comment: @mdpc, I would be personally be interested to know if anyone has a method to set permissions over webdav, with an Apache server.   AFAIK, it isn't possible.